# Parse application on android consumes 40 MB when push service started

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm implementing application which uses parse push service.
I've check it on my LG G2 phone and I see it consumes 40 MB of memory.
After removing the service from the manifest file it consumes only 2.5 MB.
Is some problem with the service configuration or it's OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just installed new PARSE lib and it solved the problem